# how to convert time series 3d numpy array to 2d panda dataframe so that it can be exported as csv

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, weka

[Kaggle Dataset and code link](https://www.kaggle.com/akshatjn000/smartphone-and-smartwatch-activity-and-biometrics)

I'm trying to solve the above Kaggle problem and I want to export preprocessed data to a CSV so that I can build a model on weka, but when I'm trying to save it in CSV I'm losing a dimension, I want to retain all the information in that CSV.
it's a time series based data

please help me with the relevant code or any resource.

Thanks

```py
print (scaled_x)

    |x           |y          |z          |label
    |1.485231    |-0.661030  |-1.194153  |0
    |0.888257    |-1.370361  |-0.829636  |0
    |0.691523    |-0.594794  |-0.936247  |0
```

```py
Fs=20
frame_size = Fs*4 #80
hop_size = Fs*2 #40
    
def get_frames(df, frame_size, hop_size):
    N_FEATURES = 3
    frames = []
    labels = []
    for i in range(0,len(df )- frame_size, hop_size):
        x = df['x'].values[i: i+frame_size]
        y = df['y'].values[i: i+frame_size]
        z = df['z'].values[i: i+frame_size]
        
        label = stats.mode(df['label'][i: i+frame_size])[0][0]
        frames.append([x,y,z])
        labels.append(label)
        
    frames = np.asarray(frames).reshape(-1, frame_size, N_FEATURES)
    labels = np.asarray(labels)
    
    return frames, labels
```

```py
x,y = get_frames(scaled_x, frame_size, hop_size)
    x.shape, y.shape

((78728, 80, 3), (78728,))
```

Comment: How is `pandas` supposed to help?  `csv` is a 2d format - matching rows and columns.  A small example of the array, and the desired `csv` might help us help you.

Comment: We need to clarify; what do you mean by 3d?  I see references to 3 spatial dimensions, `x,y,z`, but also an array shape with 3 terms `(78728, 80, 3)`.  A `csv` can have many rows with 3 columns (and a 4th for label), but it can't format a `(78728, 80, 3)` shaped array as rows/columns.

Comment: i want to use the csv file to push into the weak, what advice you want to give me so that I won't lose any information?

Comment: I have no idea what 'weka/weak' can handle or expects, so can't help with what you should write.  LIke I wrote, `csv` is normally a simple 2d text, with well defined, and consistent number of columns.